# Ошибка AttributeError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, form, url

Хочу сделать url shortener и на PAAS-платформе heroku выдаёт ошибку

```
Attribute Error : NoneType object has no attribute 'original'
```

хотя на локальном сервере всё работает и такой ошибки не происходит.

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
        original = form.cleaned_data["original"]
        shortcut = self.request.headers["Referer"] + secrets.token_urlsafe(3)
        self.request.session["shortcut"] = shortcut
        url = Url(original=original, shortcut=shortcut)
        url.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class RedirectToOriginalView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        absolute_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        url = Url.objects.filter(shortcut=absolute_url).first()
        return url.original
```

Ошибка в последней строчке,где пытаюсь достать оригинальную ссылку и произвести редирект:

```
class RedirectToOriginalView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        absolute_url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()
        url = Url.objects.filter(shortcut=absolute_url).first()
        return url.original
```

Comment: у вас `url = Url.objects.filter(shortcut=absolute_url).first()` почему-то возвращает `None`

Comment: ну это понятно) Вот и в этом вопрос,почему? В базе данных значения есть,и к тому же,как я уже и говорил,на локальном сервере всё работает и запрос в базу возвращает реальные значения

Comment: вполне возможно, что в базе значение все-таки чуть отличается от того, что находится в `absolute_url` - либо лишние пробелы есть, либо где-то идет заглавная буква вместо строчной